# I faced the missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error

Tags: r, arrays, math, logical-operators

```
   for(i in 1:length(data)){
      randomselector<-0
      
      sumofdegreesequence<-sum(data)
      
      randomselector<-runif(n=1,min=0,max=1) 
      if(i!=minindex){
      for(j in 1:length(data)){
        if(randomselector<((sum(data[1:j]))/sumofdegreesequence)){ ##Error line
          selectednextvertex<-j
        }else{
          j<-j
        }
      }
      data[minindex]<-data[minindex]-1
      data[selectednextvertex]<-data[selectednextvertex]-1
      }else{
        i<-i
      }
      
      if(data[minindex]==0){
        
        break
      }
      
    }
```

I am getting missing value where TRUE/FALSE Needed and my data is

```
data<-c(4,4,3,3,2,1,1,2).
```

I tried different things and I couldn't solve the problem

Comment: What is ```minindex``` in your above example? I tried setting it to a couple different values and was unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: minindex <- which.max(data == min(data[data>0]))
minindex taking the index of the mn value in data

Comment: Your reprex here is using random data, so it is misleading to run it without a seed and see the problem. But here it is: every now and then, your `sumofdegreesequence` is `0`, so `sum(...)/sumofdegreesequence` is `NaN`, therefore your conditional is `NA`, triggering the exit. You need to take better care with possible values and dividing by them.

Comment: Case in point: when I started with *your* version of `data` and ran this code sequence twice, it ran fine. Then I ran it a couple more times with errors. Currently my `data` is `c(4, 4, 3, 3, 2, -9, 1, -8)`, which sums to `0`.